# Add gradient to links in R networkD3::sankeyNetwork?

Tags: r, sankey-diagram, networkd3

Within the R environment, is there any way to add gradients to links with user-specified colors within the networkD3::sankeyNetwork functions?

This [repo](https://github.com/fbreitwieser/sankeyD3) expands on the functions of networkD3::sankeyNetwork, but it only seems to allow for the `linkGradient` parameter when the `LinkGroup` parameter isn't used, i.e. you can only use the gradient when all links are the same color. Unfortunately, I require `LinkGroup` to specify a different color for each link.

Here's a reproducible example of a Sankey diagram with user-specified colors for the links, but without the gradient that I'm trying to impose.

```
source = as.numeric(c("0", "0", "0", "0"))
target = as.numeric(c("1", "2", "3", "4"))
value = as.numeric(c("40", "10", "5", "20"))
group = c("red", "yellow", "green", "blue")
node = as.numeric(c("0", "1", "2", "3", "4"))
name = c("source", "red", "yellow", "green", "blue")

links = data.frame(source, target, value, group)
nodes = data.frame(node, name)

networkD3::sankeyNetwork(Links = links, Nodes = nodes, 
                         Source = 'source', 
                         Target = 'target', 
                         Value = 'value', 
                         NodeID = 'name',
                         units = 'UOM',
                         LinkGroup = 'group',
                         colourScale = JS('d3.scaleOrdinal()  
                        .domain(["miRNA","red", "yellow", "green", "blue"])
                        .range(["black", "red", "yellow","green","blue"])'))
```

Edit: Yes, there is a java option [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21206081/gradient-along-links-in-d3-sankey-diagram), but I'm looking for a solution within the R environment, i.e. via R, not java. Further, that solution doesn't work well with heavily curved links. The aforementioned [repo](https://github.com/fbreitwieser/sankeyD3) provides a much smoother gradient with curved lines. I don't know how to modify from there to allow for multiple colored links with a gradient.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gradient along links in D3 Sankey diagram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21206081/gradient-along-links-in-d3-sankey-diagram)

Comment: Basically, it cannot be done in R, not directly anyway. networkD3 just passes the data and a few options into the JavaScript code. To achieve this, you would have to (heavily) modify the underlying JavaScript code.

Comment: I've started an R package that allows the user to specify colors and create color gradients for the flows: https://ssp3nc3r.github.io/post/2020-03-30-r-package-to-create-a-ggplot-based-sankey-graphic-that-encodes-flows-with-a-color-gradient/